# 'Non-supported field type change' when modifying a feature

Tags: sharepoint, list

So, now that my previous problem was fixed, I was trying to organize the files a little bit. I found out a 'Note' type field (A multi-line textbox) was supposed to be a Multi-Pick User field. So, I decided to change that.

I seemed to change everything, but it just doesn't want to change the type. Which is much a good thing to do, seeing changing from a Note type to a User type is not supported within Sharepoint (I have no clue why, but it's probably some architectural choice).

However, I don't mind it if all the existing features get deleted, all the existing lists and their instances, and the fields.

I've also tried giving the Feature a different name, the package a different name, but nothing seems to help. Which is even more weird, since I had this problem before, and that seemed to fix it. (Still doesn't seem to be a brilliant solution anyway)

Is there anyone here that has had this problem, and knows a fix?

I've looked on Google and all, but all there seems to be is some solution for a migration from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010, and not just plain development of a custom list.

Greetings,

Mats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the feature and solution id's ? SharePoint uses the id to check if a solution/feature already exists.

Comment: This apparently got solved right when you answered this. Still trying to figure out what caused it. Apparently, when I reopened Visual Studio, it seemed to work again. I have no clue what I did to fix it. When I get this problem again (I probably will) I'll update this.